# ServerSideRender crashes block in editor

Tags: block-editor

I have a custom block that uses a render function which works fine for the front end but the as soon as I add `<ServerSideRender />` to the `edit` function of my block it just errors out with `This block has encountered an error and cannot be previewed.` and doesn't show any of the sidebar controls either.

This is my edit function:

```js
edit: function ({attributes, setAttributes}) {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps()
    
    const data = JSON.parse(attributes.data)

    const saveData = () => {
      setAttributes({data: JSON.stringify(data)})
    }

    return <div>
      <InspectorControls>
        // Snip
      </InspectorControls>
      <div { ...blockProps }>
        <ServerSideRender block="lhs-theme/feature-boxes" attributes={attributes} />
      </div>
    </div>
  },
```

I can't see any requests in the network tab that look like it trying to hit the render function.

The Dev Console logs this error:

```
Error: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
```

Comment: what is the error message in your browsers dev tools console for this problem? Also it's very unusual to store your data in a JSON string that then gets stored in an attribute and serialised into JSON by the editor. If you're trying to store repeatable content inside a block then structured data inside an attribute is a huge anti-pattern/mistake, the solution for that is nested blocks/innerblocks, much in the same way that for HTML the solution is nested tags. See how Columns and Column blocks work for an example.

Comment: That would only work for me if there is a way to sort nested blocks. I want to display a list of items in alphabetical order. One of the reasons for this rewrite is to get away from the horrific nightmare of managing our Elementor site that requires you to copy and replace every box after the one you want to add.

Comment: Are you defining `ServerSideRender` anywhere? Depending on your build process you either need to `import` it or get it from the global `wp` variable.

Comment: I'm importing it, and used a good old `console.dir` to prove that its a react element.

Comment: where's the PHP code? Note that the error it's reporting may be a PHP error, not a JS error, and this would be the block editors way of indicating the server responded with HTTP 500. Right now there isn't enough information in the question to answer it. Do you have a stack trace for the error you added to your question? Are you sure there are no errors or messages before or after it?

Comment: Nope no errors before or after, just that react error, I've added the trace but its all within the minified react dom.

The PHP works fine for the front end as I said, outputs exactly as it should.

Nothing in the PHP error log either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I found that I had a left over `save` function on my block that was throwing an error.

I removed that and ensured that `wp-server-side-render` was in the script deps.